# How to solve 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requests Error in Angular 2?

Tags: php, angular, heroku, httprequest, angular-services

**I am getting this Error:**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://heroku-app-php.herokuapp.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class testService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  getUser() {
  var tries = this.http.get(`https://heroku-app-php.herokuapp.com/`)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json());
   console.log("Res done");
    return tries;
 }

 }
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { testService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  template: `
  <div>
    <button (click)="loadUser()">Load profile</button>
    {{ profile | json }}
  </div>
  `
})
export class testComponent {
  constructor(private testService: testService) {}
  profile = {};

  loadUser() {
    this.testService.getUser().subscribe(data => this.profile = data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an Angular 2 issue. It's server side.... you are using PHP? Try and set the header in your php file(s) like so: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: i had a json and index.php file in my project.
Do i have to add this in my index.php file?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in angular enable cors in server side follow the tutorial link I gave to you

Answer (score 1):

By default no server side allow requests from external domains you should enable cors. Read this article.

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

And remember cors enable before you pass anything to `app.use`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'withCredentials' as an header to the request.

Something like :

```
this.http.get(`https://heroku-app-php.herokuapp.com/`,{ 'withCredentials': true})
```

More on that you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: where do i need to add this?

Comment: In your http request

Comment: still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the app is running on a different server than the backend.

I assume you try to make the api request while running on your local machine using `ng serve`. This however will work just fine when the code is uploaded on the same server as the backend API.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2872

As of now there is a ticket for providing support for CORS via Angular-cli but until then you You can fix this by using reverse-proxy or proxy middleware to bypass this.